# Query related to AWS EKS & cloudfront

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-eks

We have our frontend application deployed on cloudfront & backend API's are hosted on kubernetes (EKS).

We have use cases where we are using backend APIs from cloudfont (front-end). We don't want to expose Backend API publicly which is obvious.

So now the question is how should we implement above use case? Can someone please help us?
Thansk in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options to follow however more depends on you.

**Option : 1**

Change origin of frontend service instead of **S3** use **EKS** as the origin with **CloudFront**.

This might require extra things to set up and manage so not a good idea.

**Option : 2**

Set the **WAF** with **Nginx ingress controller** or in **ingress** that will be running inside the **EKS**.

with **WAF** you can specify the **domain (origin)** from a specific domain only request should accepted.

Example : https://medium.com/cloutive/exposing-applications-at-aws-eks-and-integrating-with-other-aws-services-c9eaff0a3c0c

**Option : 3**

You can keep your **EKS** behind the **API gateway** and set auth like basic auth, API key etc, and protect the **API** that way running in EKS.

https://waswani.medium.com/expose-services-in-eks-via-aws-api-gateway-8f249db372bd

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/integrate-amazon-api-gateway-with-amazon-eks/